# NetBeans nao gera a pasta lib

Tags: java, compilação, lib

Ola, bom estou com um problema ao compilar um projeto com o NetBeans 11 e jdk 13, por algum motivo estranho ao compilar a pasta `dist` vai somente o `jar` e a pasta `lib` não é compilada junto.

a mensagem gerada pelo NetBeans no final da execução é a seguinte:

```
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13/bin/java -cp C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\java\modules\ext\AbsoluteLayout.jar;C:\libs\ireport\ant-1.7.1.jar;C:\libs\ireport\antlr-2.7.6....... ETC..
```

Enfim, pelo que parece ele manda eu abrir o jar especificando todas as bibliotecas (isso pelo terminal)

não sei se é pelo algo relacionado ao `PATH` do pc, pois ja configurei o `JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13`

Alguem com o mesmo problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri

É um bug do NetBeans 9.0-11.0.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-1097

Há uma solução alternativa lá.

Basicamente, no seu arquivo `build-impl.xml` (que vai estar dentro de `nbproject`), logo após isso `<condition property="do.mkdist">` exclua isso:

```
 <not>
        <istrue value="${modules.supported.internal}"/>
 </not>
```